# The e-puck_matlab program running without stop

Tags: matlab, neural-network, webots

I used e-puck robot that avoid obstacle using braitenberg in Matlab code, the program is running without any stop, i try to put the counter such like:

```
counter = 1;

while wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) ~= -1

  if counter == 2000

save(counter,:)

 break;

  end
```

and at the end of the program i make a program save such like this:

```
save ('C:\Users\RAINAH\Desktop\data store\datastore2_net.mat','store');
```

to store the data,that can be used to train in artificial neural network, but the e-puck is still moving with a long time; so, what actually can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be because of your `TIME_STEP` variable.  It may not be changing in your loop.  Also, your `counter` isn't doing anything either.  It should probably be incrementing.

FYI: `save(counter,:)` doesn't make any sense.  Are you trying to **write a matrix to file**?  As such, do something like:

```
counter = 1;

while wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP) ~= -1

  if counter == 2000
      save matrix(counter,:); %// modified to suit your data variable
      break;
  end

  %// Do more processing code... maybe something
  %// with TIME_STEP
  %// ...

  %//**** INCREMENT COUNTER
  counter = counter + 1;

end
```

Can you **post** the entire code segment so we can see for ourselves?  This code fragment that you have put on your post cannot reproduce your error.